# The most basic question about Feature Important or Permutation_Importance

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, feature-selection

Consider the XOR gate with three inputs. The truth table will be:
[XOR 3 Inputs Truth Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F015E.png)

Now all the variables on their own are near random as far as the model is concerned. Each input 1 or 0 has a 50% chance of being classified as 1 or 0. If we are trying to use Random Forest to deduce relationships of variables which on their own should not dictate the output, how useful is feature importance? And which ones of the feature importance method will more likely provide an accurate depiction of the result?

Also, using XOR as a reference, what's the relationship in terms of data required for a random forest to create an accurate model for n features.

Comment: I think this question is better suited for Cross Validated Stack Exchange.

Comment: Provide a link please? Too much of a newb

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/